# Is there any way to get Roo to accept StringIO objects in place of files?

Tags: ruby, import-from-excel, ruby-roo

I'm trying to write some unit tests which involves [Roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) reading Excel 2007 files. I have the Excel file in my unit test file as a hex string, which in turn is fed into a StringIO instance. I can't simply pass the StringIO object to `Roo::Spreadsheet.open`, since that function actually checks if the passed object is a `File` instance:

```
def open(file, options = {})
  file = File === file ? file.path : file

  # ...
```

and if it isn't, proceeds to assume it's a string. Manually specifying the extension doesn't help:

```
doc = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file, extension: :xlsx)
```

Are there any clever ways of getting Roo to use the StringIO instance as a file?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [this version](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/) of roo has support for this. Instead of checking explicitly if it's a File class, it checks in duck-typing style if it's a stream based on whether it responds to `#seek`. The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/blob/1586ef279162f55a4e3b3e692d57b2b4ae4c8b34/lib/roo/excelx.rb#L98) and [here](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/blob/1586ef279162f55a4e3b3e692d57b2b4ae4c8b34/lib/roo/base.rb#L446).