# Opening email attachment with roo

Tags: ruby, ruby-roo

I need to manipulate xls files which are read from email attachments. Due to performance reasons I need to use the Roo gem. The problem here is passing the attachment to the Roo. Spreadsheet gem could read StringIO directly but Roo doesn't seem to have such capability. ([Is there any way to get Roo to accept StringIO objects in place of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695986/is-there-any-way-to-get-roo-to-accept-stringio-objects-in-place-of-files))

I have found this solution

```
attachment = mail.attachments.first
file = Tempfile.new(['attachment', '.xls'], :encoding => 'ascii-8bit')
file.write StringIO.new(attachment.body.decoded).read
excel = Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
```

But it involves writing a temporary file to the file system which I would like to get rid of.

Is there a way to create a virtual file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way to open an excel from email attachment with Roo.